# How do I specify in what order a event is triggered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a `autocompleteextender` object that displays results for two textboxes when you type into them. When you press either <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> it should select the item in the `autocompleteextender` and then fire the `keydown` event on the textbox to do some ajax calls.

The problem is that sometimes the `keydown` event on the textbox is triggered before the `autocompleteextender`, which means that the text in the textbox haven't been updated when the ajaxcall is made.

Is there anyway to specify in what order these events will be triggered?

EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers, however the available solutions became quite obsolete once I discovered the `OnClientItemSelected` property. I could just point that to the js function I wanted to trigger.

I didn't answer my own question since the question was about event ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the Keydown event handler and then re-assign it after your autocompleteextender event has been fired.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the autocomplete request is running async, so you are running into the problem that the keydown may well always be running in the same order, just that the autocomplete request is not finished.

Can you add a custom event to the textbox, like

```
$("txtBox").bind("afterAutoComplete", existingKeyDownHandler);
```

and then in the autocomplete request function simply trigger that?

```
$("textBox").autocomplete(...).result(function(event, item) {
    // do other stuff if required, or simply just trigger the event
    $(this).trigger("afterAutoComplete");
});
```

HTH
Alex